# Can't recieve UDP Messages in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, udp

I have been trying to get a UDP chat server working, so that it communicates on a specific port, and can find servers without knowing their IP address.  The end goal is one Pi on a robot, and another Pi as the controller.  Where I am stuck is the client sends a broadcast message and the server responds.  The client does not get the server's message.  According to Wireshark the client send the proper broadcast.  The server responds with an acknowledgment. These 2 packets look good. Then the clients sends an ICMP message back to the server, "Destination unreachable (Port unreachable)". The client displays the message it sent, as if it was what it received from the server, not what the server actually sent. I tried to check if there was a second message in the queue, there wasn't. 
I am using Ubuntu 18.04,and Raspbian - Buster, the firewall is disabled during testing. Below is the code for both the client and server.  I have commented the code with what I have tried.

I am new to Python, and this is my first post.

**From Wireshark**

Time            Source         Destination    protocol length

734 60.872408950    192.168.0.127   192.168.0.255   UDP 52  5001 → 5001 Len=10

737 60.918404508    192.168.0.90    192.168.0.127   UDP 55  5001 → 5001 Len=13

738 60.918427423    192.168.0.127   192.168.0.90    ICMP    83  Destination unreachable (Port unreachable)

**client output**

sending: "Hey_Server" to ('255.255.255.255', 5001)
waiting to receive
Received confirmation Server -- ip: ('192.168.0.127', 5001) data = b'Hey_Server'

**Server output**

Server Listening...
Received 10 bytes from ('192.168.0.127', 5001) Data: "Hey_Server"
responding...
Sent confirmation back to ('192.168.0.127', 5001) with message Server23_Here"

**Client**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from socket import *
import sys
import time

# Create a UDP socket
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, 1)
sock.settimeout(5)

# server_address = ('192.168.0.255', 5001)
# server_address = ('255.255.255.255', 5001)

# tried to set the bind a second time - same results as above
# server_address = ('', 5001) &&  client_address = ('', 5001)

# Nothing goes out on the wire
# server_address = ('127.0.0.1', 5001)
# server_address = ('127.255.255.255', 5001)
# server_address = ('0.0.0.0', 5001)

server_address = ('255.255.255.255', 5001)
client_address = ('', 5001)
message = 'Hey_Server'

sock.bind((server_address))

try:
    # Send data
    print('sending: \"' + message + '\" to ' + str(server_address))
    sent = sock.sendto(message.encode(), server_address)
    # sock.bind((client_address))

    # Receive response
    print('waiting to receive')
    udp_data = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    print('Received confirmation Server -- ip: ' + str(udp_data[1]) + " data = " + str(udp_data[0]) + '\n')

finally:
    sock.close()
```

**Server**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import socket
import sys

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

server_address = ('', 5001)
port = 5001

sock.bind(server_address)
print("Server Listening...")
response = 'Server23_Here'

while True:
    data, address = sock.recvfrom(4096)
    data = str(data.decode('UTF-8'))
    print('Received ' + str(len(data)) + ' bytes from ' + str(address) + ' Data: \"' + data + "\"")
    if data == 'Hey_Server':
        print('responding...')
        client_address = (address[0], port)
        sent = sock.sendto(response.encode('UTF-8'), client_address)
        print('Sent confirmation back to ' + str(client_address) + " with message \"" + response + "\"")
```

Comment: Change `sock.bind((server_address))` to `sock.bind((client_address))`.

Comment: I made the change.  It had no effect.  The server is sending the correct response, and the client send back" Destination unreachable".  I will add the server code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sendto the port contained in the address returned by the recvfrom "data, address = sock.recvfrom(4096)", as the port on the client side will not be the same as the one you are listening on in the server.